# give an example of an integral domain R of characteristic p>0, such that the map R->R, r->r^p is a non-surjective ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain, ring-homomorphism

I know that ring homomorphism is injective but not surjective, but I can't come up with an example with an integral domain R of characteristic p>0 such that the map is r-> r^p. I need help with this. Thank you.

Comment: Here's a hint: If you have an injective map $R\to R$ that is *not* surjective, you'd better have an infinite set for $R$. What's the simplest example of an *infinite* integral domain of characteristic $p$ you can think of?

Comment: real number R??

Comment: characteristic $p$? Do you know what that means?

Comment: no.....I'm not sure what that means.